# How to check how many remote ssh logins in my macosx

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, remote, remote-access

I allow remote ssh login to my Mac. However I only can see my local login when running command **who**. I'm sure a remote session has login my Mac via ssh.

```
localhost% who
kane     console  Jul 10 22:21 
kane     ttys000  Jul 10 22:21 
kane     ttys001  Jul 10 22:21 
kane     ttys002  Jul 10 22:21 
kane     ttys003  Jul 10 22:21
```

In a linux host, it logins my Mac via below command,

```
user     12098 11413  0 21:01 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh -L 27002:127.0.0.1:27002 -R 27002:127.0.0.1:27003 -q -N -o stricthostkeychecking=no -R 20008:localhost:6500 -R 20002:localhost:22 username@myhost.com
```

But in the linux host, **who** command can list ssh login. How can I get remote ssh login listed in my Mac?

```
user@ubuntu-server:~$ who
user     tty1         2012-07-05 18:26
user     pts/1        2012-07-23 22:10 (123.120.xxx.xxx)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have no Mac to check, but on Unix there are generally some more commands to show who is logged in:

- who (you already mentioned)
- w (with detailed information)
- users (you also tried; just shows names of currently logged-in users)
- finger (with some personal information)

So maybe one of the not-yet-tried (i.e. w, finger) does its job correctly for you? If not, some more possibilities especially for OSX are listed in the article [osx - How to know when and which user logged into the system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14127/how-to-know-when-and-which-user-logged-into-the-system-under-mac-os-x-last-is-n).

Comment: Just for curiousity: Which of them finally did it on the Mac?

Comment: both `who` and `w` are useful for identifying both local and remote sessions. I SSH'd into localhost and both of them were able to ID localhost as the origin. `last` appears to work as well.

Answer (score 3):

On ubuntu you do `last` and you can see all ssh and non ssh logins. I don't have mac here, I will try when I get back. Bug quick google search tells me it works on mac too.

Comment: `last` can list the login history. However it still has different behaviors on Ubuntu and Mac.

On ubuntu it knows which session is still logged in,
`user@ubuntu-server:~$ last
user     pts/1        123.120.xxx.xxx    Mon Jul 23 22:10   still logged in   
user     pts/1        127.0.0.1        Mon Jul 23 22:04 - 22:04  (00:00)  `

On Mac it doesn't think the ssh session is alive any more. But I can login the remote server via forwarding port. The ssh session actually is alive. 

`localhost% last
username  ttys004  114.249.xxx.xxx  Mon Jul 23 20:02 - 20:02  (00:00)`

Answer (score 0):

You can `grep` the file `/private/var/log/secure.log`:

```
grep -E "sshd\[[1-9]+\]\: Accepted" /private/var/log/secure.log
```